# ManagementEventWatcher character limit?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use eventwathcer but its not working with 11 characters process name (AbcdEfghIII.exe). If I write 10 characters process name (AbcdEfgIII.exe) its working. Is there character limit or am I doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
    Imports System.Management

    Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents StopWatch As New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"))

Private Sub StopWatch_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs)
    If e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString = "AbcdEfghIII.exe" Then
        MsgBox("Closed")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    StopWatch.Stop()
    RemoveHandler StopWatch.EventArrived, AddressOf StopWatch_EventArrived
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        AddHandler StopWatch.EventArrived, AddressOf StopWatch_EventArrived
        StopWatch.Start()
    Catch g As Exception
        MsgBox("Please, run as admin.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Define _"not working"_. Does it throw any errors? Also, put `e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString()` in a variable and then place a [**breakpoint**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) on the next line. When the breakpoint is hit, hover over the variable with your mouse to inspect its value. That way you can see if the process's name actually is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Solved now. Using the variable worked, thank you.

Comment: @VisualVincent I thought it was solved but not working again... `Dim check = e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString
        Dim check1 = "AbcdEfghIII.exe"
        If check = check1 Then
            MsgBox("closed")
        End If`  And I didn't understand that hover thing.

Comment: The reason that I told you to put it in a variable was so that you could inspect it to see if you're checking for the right name (bare in mind that your method is **case sensitive**). See this for more information about inspecting variables: [7 Ways to Look at the Values of Variables while Debugging in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: You also only need the `check` variable. `check1` is unnecessary and can be replaced by: `If check = "AbcdEfghIII.exe" Then` (note that this does not affect the outcome, only the readability of your code).

Comment: Everything is seems good, but it's still didn't work. Even with variebles its not working with 11 characters. Edit: I tried `If check = "AbcdEfghIII.exe"` also same result...

Comment: As I said the variable nor the suggested change will affect the outcome. The point was for you to _inspect_ the process name. Are you sure the casing is correct? Because or example `AbcdEfghIII.exe` is not the same as `abcdEfghIII.exe`. Try with this case insensitive check: `If String.Equals(check, "AbcdEfghIII.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then`.

Comment: If that doesn't work either, please share the _**exact**_ value you get in the `check` variable. -- To answer your title: No, WMI/ManagementEventWatcher doesn't have a character limit.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. As I said "AbcdEfghIII.exe" not working but "AbcdEfgIII.exe" working. This is just an example, if I write "QwerAsdfZxc.exe" it doesn't work neither. Here is exact exe name: "Customization.exe"

Comment: Please run this code and tell me the exact output: `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(check)))` - it converts the string into raw bytes and displays them, in order for us to see if there's a hidden character somewhere.

Comment: Well, I can't execute that code with "Customization.exe". Should I use different .exe name?

Comment: No, that would defeat the purpose of verifying the `"Customization.exe"` string. Just place my code _**outside**_ your `If` statement, for instance right after your `Dim check` declaration.

Comment: [image1](http://prntscr.com/hh1a4q) [image2](http://prntscr.com/hh1adf) [image3](http://prntscr.com/hh1ahh) and it continues to come out with different numbers

Comment: Whoops, didn't take other processes into consideration :). I wasn't expecting that many processes to close that often. Change the code to this: `MessageBox.Show(check & Environment.NewLine & String.Join(", ", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(check)))` and take a screenshot when `Customization.exe` pops up.

Comment: Here [image](http://prntscr.com/hh4yjv)

Comment: Hmm, that is odd... There is no hidden character, but the string is only 14 characters long. It's missing the `exe` part, but the dot is there.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, what happens if you try this WMI query instead: `SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'`?

Comment: Nothing happened. No msgboxes :/

Comment: Gonna write an answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there doesn't seem to be a way to make this work properly, I suppose you'll just have to use a hacky workaround: Checking if the process name starts with `Customization`.

Doing so will of course make it react to processes like `CustomizationWHATEVER.exe`, but since the code you're using for some reason doesn't return the full name there is no other way if you want it to work.

Using your initial code:

```
If check.StartsWith("Customization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Closed")
End If
```

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

> Here is a workaround:
>
> Get the `ProcessID` field instead of `ProcessName`, and use that together with [**`Process.GetProcessById()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a .NET friendly [**`Process` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) instance (from which you can extract the name).
>
> ```
> Private Sub StopWatch_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs)
>     Dim PID As Integer = CType(CType(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value, UInteger) And Integer.MaxValue, Integer)
>     Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(PID)
>
>     'NOTE: The ".exe" part is excluded in Process.ProcessName.
>     If String.Equals(p.ProcessName, "Customization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
>         MessageBox.Show("Closed")
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Nothing happened again :/ Also, I tried with shorter name like before ("Customiza") it didn't work too. Man, what a odd thing this is...

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : Like I said there is no character limit, shortening the string definitely won't work. What do you get if you show it in a message box outside the `If`: `MessageBox.Show(p.ProcessName)`? (I'm only interested in if or when it shows `Customization`)

Comment: No msgbox appear

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : Never?? Even when placing it _outside_ the `If` and when using your initial `SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace` query? And you're sure no error is thrown?

Comment: Yes, its in outside the If and using with `SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, I'm pretty sure, there is no msgbox appear. Take a look. [IMAGE](http://prntscr.com/hh5u31)

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : Wow, I honestly don't know what to tell you... This is _**really**_ odd. As I assume you're still starting it successfully, the last thing you can do is to check the [**Immediate Window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) (`CTRL + ALT + I`) while debugging to see if any error is logged. Other than that, I don't know what more to suggest.

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : Don't think so. I'm guessing it is the standard error saying that the process with ID 10040 is not running? This means that the process has terminated before your code is executed.

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : I've edited my answer. The only solution left seems to be a hacky workaround.

Comment: So basically, Customization.exe not running when the app start. The msgbox should be displayed if Customization.exe is closed while the application is running. The number like 10040 is constantly changing btw. Edit: trying new answer now

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : The error means that the _previously running_ `Customization` process was closed before your code could be executed to get information from it. And yes, 10040 is the Process ID (PID) and is a random, unique number generated for every new process that is started.

Comment: @ErokayYurdaer : Glad I could help you find some kind of solution, even though it isn't a good one. :)